# How to get two subset of an image in matlab?

Tags: matlab

If I have two threshold value T1=26 and T2=80. 
First subset have pixels less than T1 and another subset have pixels greater than T2.
Original image have pixel values between 0-255 and dimension 200*200. I want to find out the mean and variance of those subset.

Comment: What's the desired result? A 2 column matrix with pixel coordinates of each subset?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the indices of values larger than the threshold:

```
image = randi([0 255], 200); % the image data
indices_1 = find(image<26)
indices_2 = find(image>80)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, according to indices I got my subset.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that *im* is the image:

```
img_vect = im(:);
sub1_idx = find(img_vect<T1);
sub1_mean = mean(img_vect(sub1_idx));
sub1_std = std(img_vect(sub1_idx));
```

repalce  *T1* with the threshold value and repeat the same procedure with greater operator for *T2*. The code can be  merged into two lines but I separate it for clearness.